# Change iSCSI Read10/Write10 to iSCSI Read16/Write16 Without Data Loss

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi

I have inherited an iSCSI configuration that was set as Read10/Write10. That would be okay, but the need right now is to expand the existing volumes using space from an additional disk array that has been joined to the existing array group.

That has been done. I have also expanded the volumes. I was hoping to convert the disks to GPT but interestingly I think I am running into this error. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/02/18/understanding-the-2-tb-limit-in-windows-storage/

I have done some preliminary Googleing but have not come across a definitive answer on if there is a way to convert Read10/Write10 to Read16/Write16 without data loss or needing to restore from a backup. If there is, does anyone know the process to make that change with an iSCSI target running Windows Server 2012 R2 and Dell Equallogic PS6100 disk array?

Comment: Actually, EQL and MSFT have rather old and poor iSCSI target technologies and I would never use those in production. Probably it would be a good idea to get something more decent and recent.

Comment: That isn't an option in this specific case. More importantly that isn't what I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. Even if you'd manage to have a lower bus filter morphing 10 -> 16 byte CDBs you have short LBA range in your original READ[WRITE]10 commands still. Making long story short; pointless.